# how to access WinDev data base(.fic and .ndx file) in C# winform

Tags: c#, database, windev

I have .fic and .ndx file as database. I need to open it in C# and export the data to xml file. I want to know, how can i open this database in C#.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably use their HFSQL ODBC Driver.
http://www.windev.com/ts/download/

Comment: Your answer has hit the low-quality review queue. Can you please consider adding some relevant details to your post?

Comment: Thank you for good answer, I can not check it right now. When i will finish my checking i will mark it as an answer. Thank you

Comment: Hi Sourav, sometime a good answer is a simple one. Using ODBC is going to make his task real easy, he just didn't know they had an ODBC driver.

Comment: My pleasure Haider, we tested it successfully from within Excel here so it should work like a charm within C#. It uses the old ODBC specs so work fine with Microsoft products but we tried from python and it crashed, I think it's because the python libraries (pyodbc) are tied with the newer ODBC protocols.

Comment: ODBC is free or i need to pay? I know windev have fees.